# Use Rolle's Theorem to prove that if $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in some open interval $(a,b)$, then $f(x)$ is constant on $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I would think first to use the Mean Value Theorem to prove this but I need to know how to apply Rolle's Theorem as well for my Real Analysis class. I understand the theorem, but am not sure about how I'd go about using it for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_0,t_1\in(a,b)$. Let
$$g(x)=\frac{f(t_1)-f(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}(x-t_0)+f(t_0),\;x\in(a,b)$$

Then the function $h=f-g$ satisfies the hypotheses of Rolle's Theorem. Note that $h(t_1)=h(t_0)=0$, so there is some $t_2$ such that $h'(t_2)=0$. But
$$0=h'(t_2)=f'(t_2)-g'(t_2)=-\frac{f(t_1)-f(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}$$
This implies $f(t_0)=f(t_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in [a,b]$ with $x\ne a$, we can apply the Lagrange's theorem to $[a,x]$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(c)=0
\end{equation}

with $a<c<x\le b$.

So $f(x)-f(a)=0$ and $f(x)=f(a)$ $\forall x\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let define in $[a,b]$,

$\phi: t \mapsto f(t)-f(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(t-a)$

we have

$●\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$

$●\phi, $ like $f$, is continuous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$, then by Rolle's Theorem,

$\exists c\in (a,b)\;:\;\phi'(c)=0.$

$\phi'(c)=f'(c)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=0$

$\implies f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)=0$

$\implies f(a)=f(b)=Cte$.